# how can i print this data? (object data)

Tags: php, object

Var_dump result:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
 [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(71) "Tarihte Bugün Neler Olmuş? Bugünün önemli olayları! | Ttbugun.com"
    ["keywords"]=>
    string(47) "tarih,tarih dersi,tarihte bugün,günün sözü"
    ["description"]=>
    string(69) "Tarihte bugün olan olaylar ve diğer tarihi olayların hepsi burada."
    ["author"]=>
    string(17) "Yusuf Ali Bozkır"
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

using var_dump:

```
var_dump($header->headers);
```

How can i print title,description and others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
echo $header->headers{0}['title'];
echo $header->headers{0}['keyword'];
echo $header->headers{0}['description'];
echo $header->headers{0}['author'];
echo $header->headers{0}['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try casting it to array like this:

```
$array = (array)$header->headers;
```

And the as usual with assoc arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I can't try it out at the moment, but I would do something like:

```
echo $headers->headers->{'0'}['title'];
```

Comment: @Birlikisgu It seems the variable in your object is called `0`.

Comment: @Birlikisgu `$headers->headers->{0}['title']`? Unfortunately I can't test it myself...